# Sorting in bib2gls with subscript

Tags: glossaries-extra, bib2gls

Currently i try to setup bib2gls for organizing defined mathematical symbols.
Therby i've encountered the problem that when using subscripts like:

```
\ensuremath{x_\mathrm{a}}
```

is isn't sorting it corregt, wehen using

```
\ensuremath{x_{\mathrm{a}}}
```

it works. Why is the first one not working? And are there other things to be aware of?
Thank you!